# spawn n workers with GNU parallel without input

Tags: python, linux, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I would like to trigger n jobs doing the following work:

```py
# work.py
import time
import random
while True:
    print(random.randint(0,9))
    time.sleep(1)
```

where n is the number of available cores.

How can GNU parallel be used in such situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
seq $(parallel --number-of-cores) |
    parallel -N0 --line-buffered python3 -u ./work.py
```

But I wonder why you don't use Python's built-in multiprocessing, rather than introduce an additional dependency.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I initially started using the Python's multiprocessing module but realised I was writing a lot of code for little functionality. GNU parallel takes care of a lot of things behind the scenes as well as the most common traps with parallelisation. I will reconsider it later. Anyway, thanks again!